# How to automatize media renaming in kodi

Tags: xbmc, batch-rename, mediaserver, kodi, media-manager

I get media files which are not indexed by `kodi` (running on Ubuntu 15.10) - they need to be renamed first (and then they get indexed and fully processed).

I did not find any built-in solution in `kodi` to monitor and rename files - beside an [explanation](http://kodi.wiki/view/Naming_video_files) about the format they should be in. There is also a [list](http://kodi.wiki/view/Rename_tools) of recommended standalone software.

I am surprised that the renaming is no built into `kodi` and before jumping in with `cron` and [`filebot`](http://www.filebot.net/) I wanted to make sure that I will not be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I think you have to use filebot if you dont want to do this manually (https://forums.plex.tv/discussion/210382/pms-does-not-recognize-season-1-episode-1-etc-tip#latest). There are some great starters here: https://www.filebot.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2 I also know i have seen some scripts that do this automaticly on completion of torrent.

Comment: @IzznogooooD: yes, I find `filebot` to be a great tool -- this is the integration with `kodi` I was looking for (possibly as part of the extensions?)

Comment: @WoJ: Well, i use plex because i have appletv3 but as far as i know neither kodi or plex has automatic rename functions. I Imaging this would be difficult for all plugin/servers because of the permissions and possibilities for something going terribly wrong.

Comment: @Rinzwind: I checked before asking the question in the help center and in the *"Questions that you may ask"* section there is *"Running third-party applications on Ubuntu"*. I should have probably noted that I run `kodi `on Ubuntu (which indeed may not have been obvious)

Comment: Yes you should ;-)